# How to find a particular column in all tables and modify the values of that column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. Actually I want to change all the email addresses in all the tables to some fake email address. Like I want that abc@gmail.com should become abc@1234gmail.com, xyz@hotmail.com should become xyz@1234hotmail.com and so on.

I found the query that gives the tables that have email column in it. Here is the query

```
select t.table_schema, t.table_name
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.column_like '%email%'
and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by t.table_schema;
```

It is giving me some records. Now one way is go to each table and alter the values of the email column. But can I modify the above query to also get the value of each email and change it to some fake address. Like if email value is abc@gmail.com then just append 12345 or any value after the @ sign of each email address. So each email value becomes abc@1234gmail.com, xyz@1234hotmail.com and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a set of update queries for each column as below -

```
    select concat('update ', t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name, ' set ', c.column_name, ' = replace(', c.column_name, ', ''@'', ''@1234'') ') 
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.column_name like '%email%'
and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by t.table_schema;
```

This query would build one update statement per column that uses replace function to replace '@' with '@1234'. I haven't fully tested it, but hope it gives you an approach to work with.